# Mongo - Find items width key and value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to Mongo and need to find items that certain key has certain value, eg:

```
{
    "_id" : 685,
    "group" : {
        "id" : 684,
        "title" : {
            "en" : "English title"
        }
    }
}
```

So in this case I need to find items that have group id = 684.

Thanks a lot

Comment: where is 'items` presnts in your documents ? try this `db.collectionName.find({"group.id":684})` . This too simple I think posting this question you first search official site of mongDB you defiantly get you answer

Comment: Similar to  [Finding an Embedded Document by a specific property in Mongoose, Node.js, MongodDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772982/finding-an-embedded-document-by-a-specific-property-in-mongoose-node-js-mongod). You can use dot notation in the query.

Comment: so simple I couldn't find an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query:

```
db.collection.find({"group.id": 684})
```

This uses the **[dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)** to access the embedded document key.